# How to shrink curve thickness

Tags: bezier-curves

I have bunch of curve with similar thickness with different color. I want to shrink or make the thickness of the tube low. Manually doing makes a lot of time. Any trick or quick way to make the tube thickness smaller. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change a property of multiple objects simultaneously, press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> will adjusting it.

- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> drag will change the property of all objects relative
- <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> click, entering a value and pressing <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> will change the property to the same absolute value for all objects

[image]

Comment: sorry which key is this ⎇ with the Alt

Comment: Just Alt. The symbol is found on older keyboards.

Comment: when i press key and drag i cant edit or enter value. The menu moves up and down when i press alt key. https://imgur.com/a/XVYOlGj

Comment: click on value, then press alt, then drag. If you change the value, change it then press alt, keep pressing it and press enter. Leander maybe you should make a little bit clearer.

Comment: @moonboots got it. Yes Leander need to be clear little. Thanks

Comment: Alt LMB, means hold Alt press LMB. This is the standard notation for all hotkeys in Blender User Preferences (e. g. Ctrl LMB to Extrude). However, fell free to edit in your notation Atek.